# Google Map behaving Weird in Scrollable Widget (inside ListView.builder)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I need to show Google Map in ListView.builder. in Ios its behaving weird. the App Header and Bottom App Bar got scrolled with White Space. GoogleMap get freeze as well.

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: ListView.separated(
                            itemCount: state.products.length,
                            separatorBuilder:
                                (BuildContext context, int index) => SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                              return PharmaciesItemWidget(
                                pharmacies: state.products[position],
                                remove: true,
                                removeBottom: true,
                                onTap: () {
                                  BlocProvider.of<PharmaciesCubit>(context)
                                      .deletePharmacy(
                                          state.products[position].uuid);
                                },
                              );
                              // return Text("$position");
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
```

/// List Item Class

```
class PharmaciesItemWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final PharmaciesData pharmacies;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final bool remove;
  final bool removeBottom;

  const PharmaciesItemWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.pharmacies,
    this.onTap,
    this.remove = false,
    this.removeBottom = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PharmaciesItemWidgetWidgetState createState() =>
      _PharmaciesItemWidgetWidgetState();
}

class _PharmaciesItemWidgetWidgetState extends State<PharmaciesItemWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
        // Card(
        //   clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        //   elevation: 2,
        //   margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        //   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        //     // side: BorderSide(color: AppColor.primaryColor, width: 2),
        //     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        //   ),

        ClipRRect(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            // elevation: 2,
            // margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: AppColor.primaryColor,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                AppImages.pharmacies,
                                color: AppColor.backgroundWhite,
                                width: 40,
                                height: 40,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 5,
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 5,
                              child: Text(
                                widget.pharmacies.name ?? "",
                                // overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                                maxLines: 2,
                                // softWrap: false,
                                style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Spacer(),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  widget.onTap();
                                },
                                child: widget.remove
                                    ? Icon(
                                        Icons.remove_circle_outline,
                                        color: AppColor.backgroundWhite,
                                        size: 40,
                                      )
                                    : SvgPicture.asset(
                                        AppImages.right_arrow_circle,
                                        color: AppColor.backgroundWhite,
                                        width: 40,
                                        height: 40,
                                      ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 5,
                      color: AppColor.secondaryColor,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      color: AppColor.primaryBackground,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Text(widget.pharmacies.addressLine1 ?? "",
                              style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(
                                  color: AppColor.primaryColor, fontSize: 14)),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(widget.pharmacies.city + ", ",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(
                                      color: AppColor.primaryColor,
                                      fontSize: 14)),
                              Text(widget.pharmacies.stateCode + " ",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(
                                      color: AppColor.primaryColor,
                                      fontSize: 14)),
                              Text(widget.pharmacies.zip,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(
                                      color: AppColor.primaryColor,
                                      fontSize: 14)),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5,
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          // widget.pharmacies.telecom !=null ?  GestureDetector(
                          //   onTap: () => dialNo(widget.pharmacies.telecom),
                          //   child: Row(
                          //     children: [
                          //       Text(
                          //         widget.pharmacies.telecom,
                          //
                          //         style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,color: AppColor.primaryColor,),
                          //       ),
                          //
                          //       SvgPicture.asset(
                          //         AppImages.call_text,
                          //         height: 20,
                          //         color: AppColor.primaryColor,
                          //       ),
                          //     ],
                          //   ),
                          // ) : SizedBox(),

                          phoneNoWidget(
                            widget.pharmacies.telecom,
                            AppColor.primaryColor,
                          ),

                          enableMessageDebugging
                              ? Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "UUID:",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: AppColor.primaryColor,
                                          fontSize: 16),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      widget.pharmacies.uuid,
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )
                              : SizedBox(),

                          widget.removeBottom
                              ? SizedBox(
                                  height: 0,
                                )
                              : Column(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      height: 5,
                                      color: AppColor.primaryColor,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            widget.pharmacies.distanceInMiles
                                                    .toStringAsFixed(1) +
                                                " Miles Away",
                                            style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(
                                                fontSize: 18,
                                                color: AppColor.secondaryColor),
                                          ),
                                          Spacer(),
                                          // Text(
                                          //   Strings.delivery_partner,
                                          //   style: GoogleFonts.comfortaa(fontSize: 18),
                                          // )
                                          Image.asset(
                                            AppImages.lyft_logo,
                                            width: 25,
                                            height: 17,
                                            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 5,
                      color: AppColor.primaryColor,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      // decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      //   image: DecorationImage(
                      //       image: AssetImage(AppImages.map), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      // ),
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: SafeArea(
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(.8),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  child: GoogleMap(
                                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(widget.pharmacies.latitude,widget.pharmacies.longitude), zoom: 15),
                                    markers: <Marker>{
                                      Marker(
                                        markerId: MarkerId("location"),
                                        position: LatLng(
                                          widget.pharmacies.latitude,
                                          widget.pharmacies.longitude,
                                        ),
                                        infoWindow:  InfoWindow(
                                          title: "location",
                                          snippet: '*',
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    },
                                    mapType: MapType.normal,
                                    // onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                                    myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                                  ),
                                ) ,
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 5,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        color: AppColor.primaryColor,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ));
  }
}
```

these are the some pictures of the issues[image]

above is the ss of actual screen, adding ss for issues when we scroll it
[image]

Comment: `ListView` comes with it's own scroller, so you actually have a scrollview inside of another scrollview which I would guess might cause problems. Can you remove the outer `SingleChildScrollView`?

Comment: I tried without SingleChildScrollView, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I get to know today. Using Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer is costly.
There are enum property which define what it cost.

After investing many days i got to know **antiAliasWithSaveLayer** is very expensive to use.

---

hardEdge, which is the fastest clipping, but with lower fidelity.
antiAlias, which is a little slower than hardEdge, but with smoothed edges.
antiAliasWithSaveLayer, which is much slower than antiAlias, and should rarely be used.

[Visit here for more information](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Clip.html)